# how to pass data in an hidden field from one jsp page to another?

Tags: jsp, hidden-field

I have some data in an hidden field on a jsp page

```
<input type=hidden id="thisField" name="inputName">
```

how to access or pass this field onsubmit to another page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To pass the value you must included the hidden value `value="hiddenValue"` in the `<input>` statement like so:

```
<input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value="hiddenValue">
```

Then you recuperate the hidden form value in the same way that you recuperate the value of visible input fields, by accessing the parameter of the request object. Here is an example:

This code goes on the page where you want to hide the value.

```
<form action="anotherPage.jsp" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value="hiddenValue">
<input type="submit">   
</form>
```

Then on the 'anotherPage.jsp' page you recuperate the value by calling the `getParameter(String name)` method of the implicit `request` object, as so:

```
<% String hidden = request.getParameter("inputName"); %>
The Hidden Value is <%=hidden %>
```

The output of the above script will be:

```
The Hidden Value is hiddenValue
```

Answer (score 0):

The code from Alex works great. Just note that when you use request.getParameter you must use a request dispatcher

```
//Pass results back to the client
RequestDispatcher dispatcher =   getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("TestPages/ServiceServlet.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```